# XML Newsfeed load via Ajax - IE8 not working

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer-8, feed

So I have this newsfeed system which works perfectly on all browsers except IE8!

Now, the code I have was made by trial and error, so there might be some obvious coding issues which I don't know about.

Here's the external JS file (I use jQuery 1.7.2 btw)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "newsfeed_en.xml",
dataType: "html",
success: function(xml) {
$(xml).find("element:first").each(function(){
    var year = $(this).find("year").text();
    var month = $(this).find("month").text();
    var day = $(this).find("day").text();
    var date = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
    var content = $(this).find("content").html();
    var newselement = '<div class="newsElement"><h4>'+date+'</h4><p>'+content+'</p></div>';
    $('#news h1').after(newselement);
});
$(xml).find("element:gt(0)").each(function(){
    var year = $(this).find("year").text();
    var month = $(this).find("month").text();
    var day = $(this).find("day").text();
    var date = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
    var content = $(this).find("content").html();
    var newselement = '<div class="newsElement"><h4>'+date+'</h4><p>'+content+'</p></div>';
    $('#news #paneMoreNews').append(newselement);
});
}
});
});
```

`

What it does is take the first ELEMENT and put it in one location, and all the others somewhere else.

Now I had to set datatype to HTML because some ELEMENT contain LINKS, but changing it to XML doesn't resolve the problem. Taking the ":first" away doesn't solve it either.

I searched this place, but none of the other solutions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use datatype: `xml`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sites.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

    }
});
```